# What is a Circular sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

What is a circular sentence? I cannot find any meaningful explanations on the web. Is it considered good or bad? 
Could you give any examples?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, investigate more here: http://www.yourdictionary.com/circular

Comment: @esc: I can't find any mention, let alone examples, of _circular sentence_ in your link.

Answer (score 3):

I had not heard this phrase before, but it apparently is used to describe a sentence that starts and ends with the same word. It is also called an epanalepsis. ([Source](http://www.lebanon.k12.mo.us/lhs/faculty/croden/the%20new%20strategy%20of%20style.html))

It is not a bad thing. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanalepsis) states that the structure of such a sentence makes one pay special attention to it, and I agree.

One of the examples on the Wikipedia page is a well-known phrase:

> The king is dead; long live the king.

You will find such a structure only used in literary contexts, though. It is not something used in ordinary, everyday conversations.